# How to enable rich text editor using watir?

Tags: watir

Tinymce editor is used in the app. The rte toolbar is activated only if i click on the text area. I am able to focus on the Text Area using document.body.focus but still the rte toolbar doesn't show up.

Comment: Please provide link to the page where we can reproduce the problem, or provide the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rte toolbar gets enabled only after a mouse click event. So I used left mouse click event to enable the RTE Toolbar.

b=WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
b.mouseclick "left",200,550

And it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

[WYSIWYG Editors](http://watirwebdriver.com/wysiwyg-editors/) has an example on how to automate TinyMCE Editor with watir-webdriver gem.

Comment: Thanks for ur response..sorry i cant provide the html or link. Is it possible to implement it without using webdriver gem?

Comment: Ya i tried.. i am able to enter text in the text area. Only the RTE toolbar doesn't show up.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a similar editor somewhere on the web and thy to reproduce the error there. If it reproduces, then let me know and I will take a look.